# Accessor functions for containers with std::unique_ptr

Tags: c++, api, smart-pointers

I'm about to design an API where two classes exist: A data/calculation class and a container for this class. The container, however, is not simply a dumb container but also carries information on the collection as a whole that goes beyond the usual stuff that can be implemented with iterators.

So, the container basically wraps a `std::vector`, adds some precomputed attributes, utility functions, etc. What the API of the container class should also contain is

1. A method to add instances of the data/calc class,
2. accessor methods.

I do not simply want to open the `std::vector` to the public, because the addition of a new data/calc class to the container causes the re-computation of a number of attributes of the collection class. I want to, however, provide accessor method equal to the STL container accessor methods `at()` and `operator []`.

Initially, I added a private attribute of the type `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<DataClass>>`. An `addDataObject(DataObject *d)` method exists that wraps the object in an `unique_ptr` and updates the statistics.

The problem, however, comes with the accessor methods: *What would their return type be?*

- Simply returning `std::unique_ptr<DataClass> &` doesn't seem to be a clean API design: The user of the API does not need to know I use smart pointers. (See also Herb Sutter's presentation about C++11)
- Returning `DataClass *&` isn't possible, especially not for `operator []`, because I can only access the raw pointer of an `std::unique_ptr` using the smart pointer's `get()` method, which does not give me a reference.
- Returning `DataClass &` doesn't seem to make sense, especially when I'm storing pointers (heap vs. stack allocation).
- Returning `DataClass *` would violate the princpile of least surprise, because if a method is named in the sense of the STL container accessor methods, one would expect it to return a reference, especially for `operator []`.

As an illustration, this would be a simplified example:

```
class DataClass
{
    Container *m_parent;
    /* ... other member attributes/parameters ... */
public:

     /* A method that calculates something based on the attributes: */
     double someComplicatedCalculation(const double &input);
};


class Container
{
     std::vector<std::unique_ptr<DataClass>> m_collection;

     /* more attributes: maintenance info, precomputed values, etc. */

  public:

      void addDataObject(DataClass *d);

      /* What would the right return type be? */

      DataClass *&at(const int &index);
      const DataClass *&at(const int &index) const;
      DataClass *&operator [](const int &index);
      const DataClass *&operator [](const int &index) const;
};
```

Comment: What is the meaning of unique_ptr in this context? Do you want it to be invalidated when at is called? Do you want two copies of the unique_ptr to exist? Then it isn't very unique.

Comment: Is there a reason your store pointers in your vector rather than the objects themselves?

Comment: @Galik OP gets the objects by pointer and assumes ownership - why copy or move an object when you can just copy the pointer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its always difficult when you don't know *all* the details but here is what I think:

> - Simply returning `std::unique_ptr<DataClass> &` doesn't seem to be a clean API design: The user of the API does not need to know I use
>     smart pointers. (See also Herb Sutter's presentation about C++11)

Definitely yes.

> - Returning `DataClass *&` isn't possible, especially not for `operator []`, because I can only access the raw pointer of an
>     `std::unique_ptr` using the smart pointer's `get()` method, which does
>     not give me a reference.

Indeed.

> - Returning `DataClass &` doesn't seem to make sense, especially when I'm storing pointers (heap vs. stack allocation).

That does make sense. What I think may not make sense is storing pointers to begin with. A `std::vector` stores everything on the heap anyway so if that's the reason to use pointers, it doesn't apply.

> - Returning `DataClass *` would violate the princpile of least surprise, because if a method is named in the sense of the STL
>     container accessor methods, one would expect it to return a reference,
>     especially for `operator []`.

Indeed.

I would say you should return `DataClass&`. Probably you should not use pointers in your `std::vector` but if you *must* use them you can make your accessors like:

```
DataClass& operator[](std::size_t index)
{
    return *m_collection[index];
}
```

But better would be to not use pointers:

```
class Container
{
     std::vector<DataClass> m_collection;

    DataClass& operator[](std::size_t index)
    {
        return m_collection[index];
    }

    // ...
};
```

Comment: `It gives you the pointer and you can return a reference to that.` what?

Comment: @Yakk You can return references to pointers but the OP seems to think that's not possible: "Returning DataClass *& isn't possible"

Comment: @Galik You would be returning a reference to a temporary pointer. What would the point of that be?

Comment: @Barry Yes you're right, I wasn't thinking too hard about it.

Comment: I'd happily replace `vector<unique_ptr<DataClass>>` with just `vector<DataClass>`, but wouldn't that copy the object I add? I understand that, e.g., vector::push_back copies: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back. I'd like to avoid creating copies of the `DataClass` objects I add to `Container`.

Comment: @Technaton I suppose you have to weigh up the expense of copying the objects against the expense of accessing them and the complexity of managing them. Another possibility (if the system allows for it) is to provide an `emplace()` style function whereby you supply the `DataClass` constructor parameters to the container and then the `std::vector` can construct the object in-place.

Comment: @Galik Ok, I see. One last question: Wouldn't `*m_collection[index]` in the accessor, together with the Reference, allow to exchange one heap-allocated object with a stack-allocated one, leading to use-after-free when the stack is cleared? Here's a minimal, contreived example: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/7d92a78596ddf39058fb --- It works without the SIGSEGV I was expecting, but I don't know why.

Comment: @Technaton Because you return the *contents of* the address pointed to, (as a reference&) rather than the address itself (as a pointer*), your code *copies* `SomeStruct ss` replacing the contents of the `SomeStruct` pointed to by your smart pointer.

Comment: @Technaton If, for some reason, you *need* to *always* avoid *copying* then I see two options here. You either expose the fact that you use `std::unique_ptr` internally to your API users or you use some kind of *proxy* class to do your resetting of the smart pointer. Neither follows the rules of "least surprise" or how the STL works in general (if you want to mimic that). Usually containers keep a copy of their values and copying is not necessarily as expensive as you may think. Maintaining copies in the container can also have hidden performance benefits due to vectors using contiguous memory

Answer (score 2):

> Returning `DataClass &` doesn't seem to make sense, especially when I'm storing pointers (heap vs. stack allocation).

I disagree. That's what all the standard containers return. Unless the fact that you're using `unique_ptr` is something that should be visible to users  (and I'm assuming it shouldn't be), then the path of least surprise would be to just do as the standard library do: return an lvalue reference to the object.

Additionally, returning a reference makes ownership clear. If you were to return a pointer, you'd have to indicate somewhere that the user must not delete it.